# Unable to post image and text to database. Receiving no errors

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Hey guys I am having issues with my php file which is supposed to allow a user to post a status along with a picture which is uploaded to a server and its path along with the username of the user is added to the db.

DB Colomns:

- postID (A.I)
- username
- status
- imagepostpath
- timestamp (added automatically inserting a new entry)

extra info: I have changed the code from one of my already working ones, but when I attempt to test the PHP file with Postman my error is "[]".

I'm not too familiar with PHP so if you see that the mistake that I'm making is simple, please help me understand it :)
Here is my code:

```
<?php 

 //importing dbDetails file 
 require_once 'dbDetails.php';

 //this is our upload folder 
 $upload_path = '000002/';

 //Getting the server ip 
 $server_ip = gethostbyname(gethostname());

 //creating the upload url 
 $upload_url = 'http://'.$server_ip.'/Users/Images/'.$upload_path; 

 //response array 
 $response = array(); 


 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

 //checking the required parameters from the request 
 if(isset($_POST['name']) and isset($_FILES['image']['name'])){

 //connecting to the database 
 $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect...');

 //getting name from the request 
 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $status = $_POST['status'];
 $timestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

 //getting file info from the request 
 $fileinfo = pathinfo($_FILES['image']['name']);

 //getting the file extension 
 $extension = $fileinfo['extension'];

 //file url to store in the database 
 $file_url = $upload_url . getFileName() . '.' . $extension;

 //file path to upload in the server 
 $file_path = $upload_path . getFileName() . '.'. $extension; 

 //trying to save the file in the directory 
 try{
 //saving the file 
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],$file_path);
 $sql = "INSERT INTO `flare`.`tbl_user_feed` (`postID`, `username`, `status`, `imagepostpath`, `timestamp`) VALUES (NULL, '$name', '$status', '$file_url');";

 //adding the path and name to database 
 if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){

 //filling response array with values 
 $response['error'] = false; 
 $response['name'] =  $name;
 $response['imagepostpath'] = $file_url; 

 }
 //if some error occurred 
 }catch(Exception $e){
 $response['error']=true;
 $response['message']=$e->getMessage();
 } 
 //displaying the response 
 echo json_encode($response);

 //closing the connection 
 mysqli_close($con);
 }else{
 $response['error']=true;
 $response['message']='Please choose a file';
 }
 }

 /*
 We are generating the file name 
 so this method will return a file name for the image to be upload 
 */
 function getFileName(){
 $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect...');
 $sql = "SELECT max(postID) as postID FROM tbl_user_feed";
 $result = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,$sql));

 mysqli_close($con);
 if($result['postID']==null)
 return 1; 
 else 
 return ++$result['postID']; 
 }

?>
```

Comment: Is file uploaded and data NOT inserted into DB? I'm unclear as to what is going wrong

Comment: Yes sorry, the file is uploaded to the server. Nothing is added to the db though. And if i try to add another file to the server, it replaces the previous one.

Comment: One more thing you list 5 columns in query and pass in only 4 values. And use prepared statements

Comment: You are vulnerable to sql injection attacks. And unless you explicitly enabled exceptions, mysqli fails by returning boolean false. it will NOT throw anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change these lines:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],$file_path);
```

Your file path is always the same so old files are being overwritten by new...randomize it with md5()

```
$unix = time();
$file_path = $upload_path . getFileName() . md5($unix) . '.'. $extension;
```

then alter your query slightly

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `flare`.`tbl_user_feed` (`postID`, `username`, `status`, `imagepostpath`, `timestamp`) VALUES (NULL, '$name', '$status', '$file_url', '$unix')";// remove the semicolon before last double quote and add value for 5th column
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked, the files don't override when the db is working though because it auto increments the name instead of randomising. But i will use that code in future! :)

Comment: Cool...glad I could help